# Using jquery ajax, after is:checked, change the website language

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I have a checkbox styled like on ios, using the state i want to change the language of my website. I use this code:
langchange.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#langfct").change(function() { 
        if($(this).is(":checked")) { 
            $.ajax({
                url: 'langfunc.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { langstate: "fr" }
            });
            alert('fr');
            window.location.reload();
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'langfunc.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { langstate: "en" }
            });
            alert('en');
            window.location.reload();
        }
    }); 
});
```

langfunc.php

```
    <?php
    session_start ();
    $valang = $_POST['langstate'];
    $lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
    if ($valang == fr){
        include("french.php");
    }elseif ($valang == en) {
        include("english.php");
    } else{

    switch ($lang){
        case "fr":
            //echo "PAGE FR";
            include("french.php");//include check session FR
            break;
        case "en":
            //echo "PAGE EN";
            include("english.php");
            break;        
        default:
            //echo "PAGE EN - Setting Default";
            include("english.php");//include EN in all other cases of different lang detection
            break;
    }
    }
    ?>
```

How i can using the state of the checkbox, save the langstate and reload the data ? Thx

Answer (score 0):

Restructure the code as below. The issue is, you are reloading page before the ajax can complete, and possibly the ajax may not even be sent due to the blocking alert.

```
var lang = 'en'; //default
if($(this).is(":checked")) { 
    lang = 'fr';    
}

$.ajax({
     url: 'langfunc.php',
     type: 'POST',
     data: { langstate: lang },
     success: function() {
        alert(lang);
        window.location.reload();
     }
});
```